# What is the parent element for the background image?

Tags: html, css, background-image

For background-size, we can use percentage, setting the width and height of the background image in percent of the parent element. Now if the html goes like this:

```
<section>
    <p>Background-size by percentage.</p>
</section>
```

and I set up background image for `<p>`. Now which one is the parent element of the background image, `<p>` or `<section>`? Thanks.

Comment: It's the <p> tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Parent element means the background image's parent. It's `<p>`.

Try to set different width on `<p>` and `<section>`, like `width: 500px` and `width: 1000px`

You will get it.

Comment: Yes. Thanks for that. By the way, I discover that so far, width and height by percentage is all based on the parent element. Is it correct? Perhaps I haven't come across an exception.

Comment: Yes. and ```parent``` can be changed by the value of ```postion```.